# How can I give std::format the same protection against nullptr as printf has?

Tags: c++, c++20

I've rewritten the tracing code in our product to use `std::format` rather than `vsprintf` which it used previously.  It's gone well, except for one annoyance.

Some of the previous `vsprintf` trace statements would print `"null"` if a `char*` was `null`.  Now they throw `std::fmt_exception`.

I can obviously catch this exception in my `Trace()` function, but doing so relies on the developer who's added the trace statement to notice that it's potentially null.  What I really want to do is simply trace it's nullness.

I've tried doing so by overriding the format specifier, however this is only possible if one doesn't already exist..  For example:

```
import std;
#include <stdio.h>

namespace std
{
    // Add std::format specialization for const char* to provide automatic casting
    template<>
    struct formatter<char const*, wchar_t> : formatter<wstring, wchar_t>
    {
        auto format(char const* str, wformat_context& ctx) const
        {
            std::string strN(str ? str : "(null)");
            std::wstring strW(strN.begin(), strN.end());
            return formatter<wstring, wchar_t>::format(strW, ctx);
        }
    };
} // namespace std

int main()
{
    char const* bob = nullptr;

    printf("Bob is %s", bob);                                   // Outputs Bob is (null)
    std::wcout << std::format(L"Bob is: {}", bob) << std::endl; // Outputs Bob is (null)
    std::cout << std::format("Bob is: {}", bob) << std::endl;   // throws..  because I can't declare a format specialization since one already exists

    return 0;
}
```

So, can anyone tell me if there's a way to get the third case to also output "Bob is (null)" ?

Comment: Passing a null pointer to a `%s` specifier in `printf` is undefined behavior. Your C library happens to support it but it isn't portable.

Comment: `char const* to_fmt(char const* s) { return s ? s : "(null)"; }` and `std::format("Bob is: {}", to_fmt(bob))`

Comment: Related https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/226

Comment: @Eljay I did consider something like this yes, and may fall back to it.  But it'd be nice if everyone didn't need to remember special wrappers when writing trace statements.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do is wrap `std::format` and don't use it directly.

In fact, you can make it a general rule to not use `std` features directly, and make an alias namespace that exposes `std` stuff, like `mystd`.

```
namespace mystd {
  template<class...Ts>
  using vector=std::vector<Ts...>;
}
```

If you can do this work (and it is pretty mechanical), you now have a lightweight point of customization between developers and the `std` utilities they use.  Using new `std` features requires a tiny bit of initial work.

Then you can pull off your first goal - not crashing - easily by wrapping `std::format` in `notstd::format` which contains try/catch for null pointers.

To get `(you passed a null you fool!)` to be output when someone passes `nullptr`, you can do a bit of work.  Format is generally a string followed by a bunch of stuff.

```
 namespace notstd {
   namespace helpers {
     template<class T>
     T&& format_replace( T&& t ) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
   }
   template<class...Ts>
   auto format( std::string_view str, Ts&&... ts ) {
     using helpers::format_replace;
     return std::format( str, format_replace(std::forward<Ts>(ts))... );
   }
 }
```

and now I added a point of customization -- the `format_replace`.  I can add in one that takes a `char const*` and replaces it with whatever I want.

As a toy:

```
     template<class T>
     char const* format_replace( char const* str ) {
       if (str) return str;
       return "(nullptr)";
     }
```

or I could return `struct smart_string{ char const* str; }` which I could then use a formatter specialization on if I preferred that:

```
     template<class T>
     char const* format_replace( char const* str ) {
       return smart_string{str};
     }
```

Comment: Thanks!  This looks interesting.  I think the main `notstd::format` function would have to take a `std::format_string<Ts...>` rather than a `std::wstring_view` or it can't be passed to `std::format`.

As for the two `format_replace` specializations, should they be `template<>` specializations?  I'm having trouble figuring out how to get those to compile.

Comment: @Benj `format_replace` are overrides, not specializations.  Also, you might have to do something like `std::format_string< helpers::format_replace_t<Ts>... >` and do metaprogramming for that as well, where `format_replace_t<X>` is `std::decay_t<decltype( format_replace(std::declval<X>())>` or somesuch

Answer (score 0):

No complex machinery is needed just use a helper function if you know you can have nullptr's (but yes this will not give you compile time guarantees).

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

const char* from_ptr(const char* p)
{
    static const char* null = "nullptr";
    return (p == nullptr) ? null : p;
}

int main()
{
    const char* p{ nullptr };
    const char* hello{ "hello world!" };
    auto s = std::format("{} {}", from_ptr(hello), from_ptr(p));
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeh, I did consider this, but it'd be nice if people writing trace statements didn't need to remember special wrappers etc.  I might fall back to something like this if I can't get `nullptr` to be formatted automatically.

Comment: I know... let me think a bit longer ;)